# Removing all data from a csv after the 4th column using VIM

Tags: csv, vim

I have a very large 20k+ row csv file. I want to only keep the first 3 columns and delete the rest of the columns. My deliminator character is |

Below is a sample of my data. How can one do this in vim easily? I was thinking of just doing a visual block mode and delete it like that, but its possible that I might delete real data by accident. I just need vim to detect the deliminator and delete after the 3rd one.

What vim recipes are there?

[image]

Comment: `vim` is not the right tool for this use the `cut` command.

Comment: Or use block edit of vim

Comment: There are a lot of possible solution to do this in vim. Like `:%norm 3f|d$` but vim isn't really fast with long lines and huge files. I mean it is way better than most text editors, but I stand in a line here with @OrtomalaLokni and would suggest a commandline tool like `cut`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim wouldn't be good for this. Best to use the following cut command that worked:

> **cut -d'|' -f2,3**

d is for what deliminator it is

f is what columns you want. in my case it was 2 and 3.

Comment: To do this within vim… select the lines you want to operate on, `:'<,'>!cut -d'|' -f2,3`. Vim replaces the selection with the filtered version. Better to delegate this to a tool which was built for it. `cut` is the perfect tool for the job. This is also the Vim way as it would get it done in the least key strokes

Answer (score 5):

Use a `normal` command over all the lines in the text file.

`:%normal! 3f|D`

- `%` for all the lines in the buffer
- `normal!` apply the normal command (beginning in the first column of the line)
- `3f|` find the third occurrence of `|`
- `D` delete from the current cursor location to the end of the line.